# Tests using Nock fail in CircleCI due to cross-origin forbidden error

Tags: javascript, jestjs, circleci, nock

I am using [Nock.js](https://github.com/nock/nock) to mock response from API for my tests written in Jest. All the tests pass locally, however in `CircleCI`, these tests using `Nock` fail. The error is:

```
Error: Error: Nock: No match for request {
        "method": "OPTIONS",
        "url": "http://localhost:9000/loggedinuser/",
        "headers": {
          "origin": "http://localhost",
          "access-control-request-method": "GET",
          "access-control-request-headers": "Authorization",
          "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (linux) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) jsdom/11.12.0",
          "host": "localhost:9000",
          "content-length": 0
        }
...
Error: Cross origin http://localhost forbidden
...
```

The test looks like this:

```
  it('should successfully fetch user details ', done => {
    nock(API_ENDPOINT)
      .get('/loggedinuser/')
      .reply(200, {
        token: 'a mock token',
      });
  ...
```

Thank you

Comment: Not a lot to go on, but Nock is not matching the request because it's a OPTIONS request when you're nocking a GET. Does your app intentionally make an OPTIONS call?

Comment: No, it doesnt, to my knowledge. This particular one is a `get` request.

Comment: But the request that Nock is intercepting under the hood is an OPTIONS request. So it's coming from somewhere. :shrug: